# Presenting public facing error page

Tags: php, error-handling

If a non-recovery error is discovered in `set_error_handler()`, `set_exception_handler()`, or`register_shutdown_function()`, I log the error and present a public facing message apologizing for the error.

For non-ajax requests, how should the message be presented?  Redirect to a separate error message page?  Make the request which caused the error return the error message HTML?  Something else?  If there is not one single answer, what are the pros and cons of the different solutions?

Comment: @Epodax  Unless one solution is the undeniable favorite of all.  If not, there are pros and cons.  May I ask what you use?  Thanks

Comment: On hold?  Seems like Deceze definitely believes there is a right answer and wrong answer, and not opinion based.  There are also four people that upvoted him who feel the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Speaking from the point of view of the HTTP protocol, the server must generate a 5xx error status code and optionally return an error page to signify *"something unexpectedly went wrong in processing this request."* A redirect is not a correct response in this case.

Comment: Why is a redirect not a correct response?  Regardless, I will do as you recommend.  Thanks

Comment: Because a redirect signifies *"your request can be answered elsewhere."* Well, it can't. So don't send the client elsewhere.